# TypeError: res.render is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js, router

I am having an issue with nodejs' res.render, it's telling me its not a function. I've looked at other posts on stack overflow and they do not solve my issue.

Here's the issue....

My app has a controller, called auth.js

In it, it exports this function called updateDiscount

```
exports.updateDiscount = (req,res,next) =>{

    const { discounts, email, filename, decide } = req.body;

    switch(decide){
        case "Approve":
            approve(discounts,email,filename,decide, req, res);
            break;
        case "Deny":
            deny(discounts,email,filename,decide, req, res);
            break;
        case "Defer":
            defer(discounts,email,filename,decide, req, res);
            break;
        default:
            return res.render('adminGrantPortal', {
                message: 'You selected an option from the -- Approve/Deny/Defer -- menu which does not exist. Please contact your system administrator'
            });
    }
}
```

Next I have a WORKING METHOD called approve. So when the controller gets the approve message ( via variable *decide* in the switch ) It will approve a users discount in the DB. Again, this method is working...

```
approve = (discounts, email, filename, decide, req, res) =>{

    // get discount based on name
    mysqlConnection.query('SELECT id FROM discounts WHERE name=?', [discounts], async (error, results)=>{
        if(error){
            return res.render('adminGrantPortal',{
                message: 'One or more fields either, do not exist in the database, or were filled out incorrectly during your last action.'
            });
        }
        console.log('ayayay');
        console.log(results[0]);
        let discountID = results[0].id;

        // Set staus in files table
        mysqlConnection.query("UPDATE files SET status='approved' WHERE email=? AND filename=?", [email,filename], async (error,results)=>{
            if(error){
                return res.render('adminGrantPortal',{
                    message: 'Could not update users status, because it is not found in the database.'
                });
            }

            // Add to discounts_users
            mysqlConnection.query('INSERT INTO discounts_users (email,discountID) VALUES (?,?)',[email,discountID], async (error,results)=>{
                if(error){
                    return res.render('adminGrantPortal', {
                        message: 'Cannot update the database, maybe this user already has this discount.'
                    });
                }
                return res.render('adminGrantPortal', {
                    message: 'Approved discount eligibility successfully.'
                });
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Now, I have a deny method, which means when the req.body.decide = 'deny' it goes here. This method gives me the error, specifically the line after the console.log('success');

```
deny = (discounts, email, filename, req, res) =>{
    // Set staus in files table
    mysqlConnection.query("UPDATE files SET status='denied' WHERE email=? AND filename=?", [email,filename], async (error,results)=>{
        if(error){
            console.log('error');
            return res.render('adminGrantPortal',{
                message: 'Could not update users status, because it is not found in the database.'
            });
        }
    });

    console.log('success');
    return res.render('adminGrantPortal', {
        message: 'Denied discount eligibility successfully.'
    });
}
```

Why does it do this?

I've narrowed down some things that it is not.

1. I believe it is not that my 'results' object being returned from the mysqlconnection shares the same name as my **res** object, which would control the headers.
2. I believe it is not anything to do with my mysql, because I removed it to look like this...

```
deny = (discounts, email, filename, req, res) =>{
    console.log('success');
    return res.render('adminGrantPortal', {
        message: 'Denied discount eligibility successfully.'
    });
}
```

Yet I still get the same error....

```
TypeError: res.render is not a function
    at deny (C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\Project\racf\client\controllers\auth.js:187:16)
    at exports.updateDiscount (C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\Project\racf\client\controllers\auth.js:127:13)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\Project\racf\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\Project\racf\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\Project\racf\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\Project\racf\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\Project\racf\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\Project\racf\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\Project\racf\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at Function.handle (C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\Project\racf\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
```

Can anyone help me to figure out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `res.render(...)` is part of `express` module. Are you using `express` module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When calling the `deny` function, you are passing `req` as the 5th argument but you are trying to use it as `res` inside the function. Add `decide` to the `deny` function's argument list after `filename`.

```
deny = (discounts, email, filename, decide, req, res) => {
  // ...
}
```